# Best flutter charts library with zoom and scroll?

Tags: flutter, charts

what's the best flutter library ( android and ios ) for zoom and scroll charts like this video?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXaTa.jpg

I'm searching a lot, but not find any useful library this, maybe there's a good library to start on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try [interactive_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/interactive_chart) package for that.

**EDIT:**
after some research I found this package called [graphic](https://pub.dev/packages/graphic),its much more better then the first suggested package.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start, but the library is not updated from 14 months, and seems its only for candle stick bar.